# Regex find specific tags for replace in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a string with some codes (ex:«USER_ID#USERNAME#STATUS»)  for replacement like in this example:

> Hello «USER_ID#USERNAME#STATUS», do you like «PROD_ID#PRODNAME#STATUS»?

I need to find a way to get all the codes for future replacement.

I can easily find one code with this regex:

```
/«(.*)#(.*)#(.*)»/
```

but can't find a way to get all the codes with preg_match_all.

Can someone help me? I'm using PHP.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have to make your pattern non-greedy:

```
/«(.*?)#(.*?)#(.*?)»/
```

See [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = "Hello «USER_ID#USERNAME#STATUS», do you like «PROD_ID#PRODNAME#STATUS»?";

preg_match_all('/«(.*)#(.*)#(.*)»/U',$string,$matches);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

gives

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(25) "«USER_ID#USERNAME#STATUS»"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "«PROD_ID#PRODNAME#STATUS»"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "USER_ID"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "PROD_ID"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "USERNAME"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "PRODNAME"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "STATUS"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "STATUS"
  }
}
```

Note the use of the Ungreedy switch.

I'm sure somebody will be along soon to modify the regexp so that it's inherently ungreedy

Comment: sorry, by bad, io copied your sample to save code writing and hit the downvote, gave you an upvote for the inconvenience and that your code is ok

Comment: @Robert - you're better using Artefacto's example that makes the pattern ungreedy, rather than the ungreedy switch; but thanks anyway

Comment: my example is below, im not using greedy matching, `(?<x>.*?)`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
preg_match_all('/«(?<id>.*?)#(?<username>.*?)#(?<status>.*?)»/',$string,$matches);
echo $matches[0]['username'];

//And dont forget you have to loop.
foreach($matches as $match)
{
    echo $match['username'];
}
```

:)

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "«USER_ID#USERNAME#STATUS»"
    [1]=>
    string(27) "«PROD_ID#PRODNAME#STATUS»"
  }
  ["id"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "USER_ID"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "PROD_ID"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "USER_ID"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "PROD_ID"
  }
  ["username"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "USERNAME"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "PRODNAME"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "USERNAME"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "PRODNAME"
  }
  ["status"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "STATUS"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "STATUS"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "STATUS"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "STATUS"
  }
}
```